# Why does Camgear youtube video download run normally but doesn't save any result in the path?

Tags: opencv, video, video-processing

I am using the below code from github to download youtube videos with Camgear as frames and it runs normally but whenever I open the path it's still empty, any idea why this could be ?

```
### Capturing images from YouTube videos without downloading Video using Python's VidGear Module
## pip install vidgear
import cv2
import os
from vidgear.gears import CamGear

### Replace this youtube video link with your one
# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQc432kUOpM
stream = CamGear(
    source="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69X8ZLj1ukw",
    stream_mode=True,
    time_delay=1,
    logging=True,
).start()

# this should be the path where u want ur images
# path  = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Capture Frames from Online YouTube Video\\cars\\'
path = "D:\\github codes\\test\\"

currentframe = 0
while True:

    frame = stream.read()  ### using functions from vidGear module
    if frame is None:
        break

    cv2.imshow("Output Frame", frame)  # optional if u want to show the frames

    name = path + "./frames" + str(currentframe) + ".jpg"
    print("Creating..." + name)

    cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
    currentframe += 5  ##chnage 5 with the number of frames. Here 5 means capture frame after every 5 frames
    ###usually videos are 30fps so if here 30 is provided a frame will be captures after every second.

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
stream.stop()
```